# How do I add web parts to a document set's welcome page that depend on metadata set in each individual document set?

Tags: document-set

We are using custom content types that inherit from document sets. These document sets have metadata, which we would like to use in web parts on the document set's welcome page.

For example: we would like a tag-based content search in our site collection for any content that uses the same tag as our document set.
To make things more real: we have a content type "animals" that is a document set plus metadata; one of these fields is a managed metadata field "animal name", and we would like to pull all photographs that we have in our site collection with the same tag into the document set's welcome page via a web part.

Is that possible? How?
If not: is there some way to achieve something similar?

Solution for SP2013 preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a version. Here is the process for SP2013.

1. Ensure your metadata column is a managed property. (Default name would be 'owstaxidAnimalName')
2. Edit the Doc Set Welcome Page.
3. Add a Content Search Web Part (in the Content Rollup section)
4. Edit the CSWP properties
5. Click Change Query
6. Switch to advanced mode
7. Choose Local System results (or other result source as appropriate)
8. In the filter box, enter the following expression, changing the column name and managed property names as appropriate:

   owstaxidAnimalName:{Page.Animal_x0020_Name}

Comment: Thank you, this works well. How to do this with a CQWP?