# How do I perform a query on a document set welcome page using keywords from the document set?

Tags: 2013, document-set, cswp, enterprise-keywords

I have been creating a work-handling process for a materials testing group, and I want the users to be recommended related content. I created a document set that handles their jobs, and one that handles their material specs. Both document sets have a metadata keywords field. when the users create a new "job" document set, I want them to be recommended material specs based on the keywords field.

I read this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97425/how-do-i-add-web-parts-to-a-document-sets-welcome-page-that-depend-on-metadata), which I believe is exactly what I want, but this process is not working for me. On the "job" document set welcome page, the {page} query variable is empty, and I think this is why I am having issues. Does anyone know how I can get this search to work?

I am using SP 2013

[image: both the site and listitem variable are null]